# how to require a .js file in node repl

Tags: node.js

so i usually use ruby irb, and I can pull .rb files I wrote into the console environment by running

```
load './script.rb'
```

and then all of the functions I wrote in script.rb will be available.

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to do this in the node "console" environment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load JavaScript files using the `require` function. The following example assume that the Node.js process was started at the directory where your file is located.

```
require('./script.js');
```

This will execute the contents of the file.

If you have exported functions or objects, you can assign them to a variable and use them later.

```
const myFunction = require('./script.js').myFunction;
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 4):

Like many other development frameworks/languages, Node has a [Modules/Package System](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_modules) which, is a CommonJS variant. To load a Module use [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_require). The usage of `require()` is the same when running JavaScript files or running in the REPL.

You can require Node Core Modules, [NPM](https://npmjs.com) Installed Packages or your own local modules. When loading NPM Packages specified in a `package.json` or a local module, Node will load them from the Current Working Directory(CWD), you can check this using [`process.cwd()`.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) The CWD will be set to the absolute path of the directory you launched the REPL from.

You can launch the REPL via running `node` in your CLI and require your packages like below.

```
// Core Package
const os = require('os')
console.log(os)

// NPM Package
const moment = require('moment')
console.log(moment)

// Local Package
const myPackage = require('./myPackage')
console.log(myPackage)
```

You can also pre-require module(s) using the `-r` flag when running `node`. The below will launch the Node REPL with the `os` package preloaded. You can then access the `os` package using the variable `os`

```
node -r os
console.log(os)
```

In the future, Node may also support [ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (ie. `import`). You can read more detailed info about that in the [Enhancement Proposal](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es-modules.md).